# Turn off Restrict background data programmatically

Tags: android

I have a HTC one M8 running Android 5. I have gone into settings -> more -> data usage -> restrict background data (checked)

This should turn background data off.

I would like to turn it back on (uncheck the checkbox) programmatically with the following code in onCreate of one of my Activities.

```
ContentResolver.setMasterSyncAutomatically(true);
```

.
Unfortunately it doesn't turn back on. I have the following in the manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SYNC_SETTINGS" />
```

Are there any ideas why this isn't working?

thanks in advance

Comment: did you find solution to this?

Comment: @gikarasojokinene Hi it isn't possible i'm afraid with standard Android. You could potentially try integrate Samsung Knox into your app. This may give you the power to achieve this but then you are locked into samsung handsets.